# Как создать и управлять txt файлом в облаке с помощью python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Сейчас работаю над телеграмм-ботом, задачей которого является автоматическая рассылка домашки и расписания одноклассникам после уроков. За обновление и добавление дз отвечает друг. Моя идея заключается в том, что бы создать где-то (не знаю где) .txt файл, и как-то (не знаю как) получать к нему доступ, парсить и класть в словарь, ну а оттуда уже легко использовать.

Так вот, как думаете - это оптимально?
Подскажите как можно реализовать?
Может, кто-то знает способ получше?

P.S. 15 лет, 9 класс, так что не сильно знаком с облаками, и т.п., но на питоне пишу уже достаточно давно, так что прошу обьяснить как для блондинки.

Comment: кто должен иметь доступ к этому файлу кроме бота ? бот запущен на домашнем пк ? может вместо облака рядом с ботом его разместить ?

Comment: Здравствуйте, @Интик. Да, код для бота у меня на ноуте. что вы имеете ввиду под "рядом с ботом", смысл в том что код пишу я, а контент обновляет другой человек, бот берет контент и рассылает

Comment: сложный вариант эксель таблица на облаке в гугле https://habr.com/ru/post/483302/

Comment: что, если дать другу возможность отправить боту актуальный txt файл?..

Comment: @Jack_oS как вариант на первое время подойдет., но в итоге я хочу сделать все в облаке и автоматизировать так, что бы было удобно работать, но это тоже не плохое решение